# How to set sql_mode hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, sql-mode

Is there a way to set the sql_mode (for MySql database) in Hibernate properties or in connection string?

Thanks,

Stefano

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) sessionVariables property which is defined as follows can be used in JDBC connection string:

> A comma-separated list of name/value pairs to be sent as SET SESSION
>   ... to the server when the driver connects.

List of values goes inside single quotes:

```
sessionVariables=sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES'
```